# In SQLAlchemy, what's the difference between DBSession and DBSession()?

Tags: sqlalchemy

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine)

#1
DBSession.add(someobject)
DBsession.commit()

#2
session = DBSession()
session.add(someobject)
session.commit()
```

What's the difference between **#1** and **#2**?

I use **#1** in my Pyramid app and there're a lot of exceptions of 'MySQL has gone away'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any as sqlalchemy [makes most Session methods also available as classmethods](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped_session#sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session) for ScopedSessions. This includes `add()` and `commit()`.

Comment: session(=DBSession()) is thread_local while DBSession is not?

Comment: `DBSession()` creates a thread-local instance of the `DBSession` class. Calling the `add()` or `commit()` class methods on the `DBSession` class automatically createas a thread-local instance if none is present yet and routes the method call to that instance.